# BigQuery Schema error despite updating schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run multiple simultaneous jobs in order to load around 700K record to a single BigQuery table. My code (Java) creates the schema from the records of is job, and updates the BigQuery schema, if needed.

Workflow is as follows:

1. A single job creates the table and sets the (initial) schema.
2. For each load job we create the schema from the records of the job. Then we pull the existing table schema from BigQuery, and if it's not a superset of the schema associated with the job, we update the schema with the new merged schema. The last part (starting from pulling the existing schema) is synced (using a lock) - only one job performs it at a time. The update of the schema is using the UPDATE method, and the lock is released only after the client update method returns.

I was expecting to avoid encountering schema update errors using this workflow. I'm assuming that once the client returns from the update job, then the table is updated, and that jobs that are in process can't be hurt from the schema update.

Nevertheless, I still get schema update errors from time to time. Is the update method atomic? How do I know when a schema was actually updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates in BigQuery are atomic, but they are applied at the end of the job. When a job completes, it makes sure that the schemas are equivalent. If there was a schema update while the job was running, this check will fail.

We should probably make sure that the schemas are compatible instead of equivalent. If you do an append with a compatible schema (i.e. you have a subset of the table schema) that should succeed, but currently BigQuery doesn't allow this. I'll file a bug.

Comment: For a load job that doesn't contains a schema (only data), what is the schema associated with this job (the one that will fail in "making sure the schema are equivalent"). Note that in my use case, no job (expect the one creating the table) contains a schema. All schema updates are done using UPDATE table, all load jobs don't contain a schema.

Comment: The schema from when the job started gets copied and verified at the end of the job. This is designed to prevent an incompatible schema change (e.g. with a truncate table job) from happening while the load job is running, and then having the new data commit and corrupt the table. This could look like: 1. start load job 2. truncate the table and change schema 3. load job commits with the old schema.